# API for Google Wallet Merchant Center

Tags: android-pay

When I log in to Wallet Merchant Center I can see a list of orders that correspond to my application's in-app purchases. Is there an API to get the same information?

I found the [following page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/package-summary) but I couldn't find the thing I'm looking for there.